# Telerik Reporting Layout issue when multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In a legacy project we are using an old version of telerik reporting (q3 2013) where we create a PDF report. We have a master/subreport where one of the subreports content is added in code. When there is enough items that require it to render on next page we can see that the 2nd item on page2 is rendered on top of the first item. I get the same behavior even if I add a panel instead of our custom control. The report that is used only contains one panel item where keeptogether is set to true.

[image: Screenshot of report]

```
 private void ContractualInformationChartItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        panel.Items.Clear();
        panel.Width = Unit.Inch(4.82);
        var week = int.Parse(ReportParameters["Week"].Value.ToString());
        var year = int.Parse(ReportParameters["Year"].Value.ToString());
        var regionId = int.Parse(ReportParameters["RegionId"].Value.ToString());

        using (var provider = new Provider())
        {
            var report =
                new TimeReportService().GetOrCreateWeeklyReport(week, year, provider)
                 .WeeklyRegionReports.First(wr => wr.RegionId == regionId && wr.DeletedBy == null && wr.DeletedDate == null);
            if (report.ContractualInformations != null && report.ContractualInformations.Any())
            {
                foreach (var rig in report.ContractualInformations.Where(r => r.DeletedBy == null && r.DeletedDate == null).Select(zt => zt.Rig).Distinct())
                {
                    //The code for the chart can be replaced with a new panel with yellow background and the issue is still the same
                    var budget = new ContractualInformationService().GetContractualInformation(report.WeeklyReport.Week, report.WeeklyReport.Year, rig.Id, ContractualInformationType.Budget, provider);
                    var forecast = new ContractualInformationService().GetContractualInformation(report.WeeklyReport.Week, report.WeeklyReport.Year, rig.Id, ContractualInformationType.Forecast, provider);
                    var chart = new ContractualInformationChart(budget, forecast)
                    {
                        Docking = DockingStyle.Top,
                        Height = Unit.Inch(1.35),
                        Width = panel.Width,
                    };

                    chart.Style.Padding.Bottom = Unit.Inch(0.05);
                    panel.Items.Add(chart);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any screenshots, code, or a description of how it's configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is Docking = DockingStyle.Top. Replacing this with Location and calculate y value based on loop count solved the layout issue